# ScanSnap iX100 inexplicably no longer recognized

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner

I've got a Fujitsu ScanSnap iX100 which I periodically use to scan papers. I'm using the `scanimage` command with the argument `-d "fujitsu:ScanSnap iX100:6550"` to identify my scanner.  This has worked for many months.  However, today when I went to do my weekly scanning I got this message:

```
scanimage: open of device fujitsu:ScanSnap iX100:6550 failed: Invalid argument
```

When I ran `scanimage -L` it says no scanners were identified, and suggested that I run `sane-find-scanner`.  This command also found nothing, even when run as root.

The only thing I did notice was in dmesg:

```
usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
```

This does not seem to coincide with the scanner itself, although I have seen it occasionally when trying to recognize the scanner.

But the scanner appears to be working fine and is ready to scan.  The lights come on as expected, it does its "test feed" when it's first connected, and it just a preliminary pull on anything I feed it to get itself ready to scan.

I have three USB ports and have tried all of them.  I also tried a reboot, with no luck.

I tried running `lsusb` but it doesn't mention the scanner.  I'm running Ubuntu 21.04

What else can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Update: Since 21.04 is apparently not on topic here, I tried with a different machine running 18.04.  On this machine I get the same lack of detection but a lot more messages in dmesg:

```
usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: device not accepting address 30, error -71
usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: device not accepting address 31, error -71
usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: device not accepting address 34, error -71
usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 35 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: device not accepting address 35, error -71
usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

And from there it appears to keep trying to assign new addresses, currently over 100.

Update:

I replugged the device and this time I got this in dmesg and it I could see it from scanimage:

```
usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 60 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04c5, idProduct=13f4
usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-1: Product: ScanSnap iX100
usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Fujitsu
```

But then while I was trying to set up a command to start scanning it stopped working again, and from dmesg I see that almost exactly 300 seconds later it said this:

```
usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 60
usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 61 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-1: device not accepting address 61, error -71
usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 62 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04c5, idProduct=13f4
usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-1: Product: ScanSnap iX100
usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Fujitsu
usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 62
```

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: @guiverc I'll try it on my 18.04 machine then